# Positioning image under div in css

Tags: css, positioning

I've got a question regarding positioning of two objects: image and div. **I want bg2.png image to stay under div.** I keep encountering problem with image pushing div down by img's height. How do I avoid that?

I tried pushing down image with "top:" value but of course it leaves me with empty area above div. Also I tried adding negative "top:" value and relative position to "maincontent" div but again it left me with empty area, only difference was that this time it was under the div.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
 <img src="./images/bg2.png" class="bgimg" />
 <div id="maincontent">
 </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
.bgimg {
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 70px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#maincontent {
    height: 520px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

edit - what I'm trying to achieve:
[Click me!](http://oi48.tinypic.com/2iihldw.jpg)

Comment: why not use:

`#maincontent {
background-image:('./images/bg2.png');
}`

Comment: Argh, stupid me. I forgot to add that I do not want to keep WHOLE image under div, just a part of it. Like in that example:
[link](http://oi48.tinypic.com/2iihldw.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 solutions:

Change your HTML structure:

```
<body>
 <div id="maincontent">
 </div>
 <img src="./images/bg2.png" class="bgimg" alt="some">
</body>
```

or make it as the background-image:

```
<body>
  <div id="maincontent">
  </div>
</body>

#maincontent {
 background: url(./images/bg2.png) no-repeat 0 100%;
 padding-bottom: height_of_image_in_px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
body {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
.bgimg {
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 70px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#maincontent {
    height: 520px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    z-index: 8;
}

</style>

<body>

 <div id="maincontent">
     <img src="./images/bg2.png" class="bgimg" alt="some info about image here">
 </div>
</body>
```

if you want that image inside the div use this code. or if you want make that image background of that div use css background property